# How to make a UIImageView with touch to go to other ViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard

I have a `StoryBoard` and a base `ViewController` include some images.

How I can touch an image of them to go to other `ViewController` linked that `UIImageView` by modal?

Comment: Make it subview of the common ancestor view of the source view and the destination view, then subview to the correct view when the touch finished/cancelled.

Comment: Sr but you can answer clearly, I'm newbie.Thanks!

Comment: I'm not even sure the approach is a good approach (it works, but I don't know it is good or not). This was how I implemented the dragging between views: https://github.com/nhahtdh/PS5/blob/master/Game/GameObject.mm#L204

Comment: if you are using imageviews then I dont think you can do it directly from storyboard, you have to do it programmatically using tap gesture maybe.

Comment: but if you have custom buttons with those images then simply control+drag from the button to the respective viewcontroller you wan to segue and assign desired type of action like touchUpInside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create the new `viewController`
drag a tap gesture recognizer to the first `viewController`

`right click + drag` from the gesture recognizer to the new `viewController` and you will see the option `modal`

`right click + drag` from the `UIImageView` to the `gestureRecognizer` and you will see the `gestureRecognizer` option select it and that's all

Make sure the `UIImageView` have the "User Iteraction Enabled" option ckecked

just added a sample project to my [github](https://github.com/jcesarmobile/ImageTapGestureStoryboard)

Comment: I did but it not worked, on the simulator I touched image and nothing happen

Comment: Did you follow the steps correctly? I created a new test project and worked this way

Comment: and make sure the UIImageViews have the "User Interaction enabled" checked

Comment: I had done, I dont change '(IBAction)pisces:(id)sender{
}' to '(IBAction)pisces:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
}'. So now it work good.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following to move from one view controller to another:

```
[MyImageView.view removeFromSuperview];
[MyNewViewController.view addSubview:MyImageView.view];
```

If you wish to animate that change making it fly its way, you might need to create animation for MyImageView.view.frame from the old to the new view controller. For that you'll need to use methods like

```
CGRect fromFrame = [MyImageView.view convertRect:MyImageView.view.frame toView:MyOldViewController]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using buttons instead of images?

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/uiimageview-touch-handling-uibutton/